# Use while loop to check for the condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I was trying to make this program in which every time when the users enter a number, if the number is in the range between 0 and 2, it will return the number the user has inputed. Otherwise, it will keep printing out the statement "Enter selection: " to the console until the user has entered a value that is in the range. My problem is it seems like my while loop is not working so that every time no matter what value I enter (even it's outside the range 0, 2) the value still returns.

Below is my existing code:

```
def get_user_option_input():
    number = input('Please enter a number: ')
    num = int(number)
    while not num > 0 and num < 2:
        print('Enter selection: ')
    return num
 
number = get_user_option_input()
print(number)
```

Hope someone can help me figure this out. Much appreciated!

Comment: `while not (num > 0 and num < 2)` - ordering matters

Comment: `while num < 0 or num > 2` or `while num not in [1, 2]` seem easier to understand.

Comment: Or `while not 0 <= num <= 2`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
def get_user_option_input():
    # Set num to something that is not in the valid range
    num = -1
    # Do until num is between 0 and 2
    while not (num > 0 and num < 2):
        # Get user input
        number = input('Please enter a number: ')
        num = int(number)
    return num

number = get_user_option_input()
print(number)
```

Take note of the importance of `()` in the `not (num > 0 and num < 2)`. Now the `not` negates both `num > 0 and num < 2`. Where as before, the `not` negated only the `num > 0` part of the `boolean` condition.

Answer (score 0):

If the first number the user inputs is outside the range, then it will run `print('Enter selection: ')` forever, because `num` is never changed inside the loop. To fix this you need to change `print('Enter selection: ')` to `num = int(input('Enter selection: '))`. Also, change `while not num > 0 and num < 2:`to `while not (num > 0 and num < 2):`. Otherwise, `not` only negates `num > 0`. By adding a parentheses, `not` negates both `num > 0` and `num < 2`.